# JWT Token based Authentication in Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, jwt, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

i m getting below Error in startup.css while  authenticateing token issued by Azure AD

**JwtBearerAppBuilderExtensions.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(IA‌​pplicationBuilder, JwtBearerOptions)' is obsolete: 'See go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=845470';**

And my code is

```
 app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                Authority = String.Format(Configuration["AzureAd:AadInstance"], Configuration["AzureAD:Tenant"]),
                Audience = Configuration["AzureAd:Audience"],
            });
```

Any suggestion please i am new to Azure and web API?
Thanks

Comment: Did you read the link: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1310? Authentication changed a bit in 2.0, That way of defining the authentication middleware is now obsolete.

Comment: Hi @juunas Thanks for reply ,yes  i have already Check this link but couldn't figure out how to deal with my problem.If u have some code or more info ,that would b a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and with the below code  i got it working now..Thanks

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
          .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
          {
              jwtOptions.Authority = String.Format(Configuration["Logging:AzureAd:AadInstance"], Configuration["Logging:AzureAD:Tenant"]);
              jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["Logging:AzureAd:Audience"];
              jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
              {
                  OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
              };
          });

            services.AddMvc();
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {

            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }

        private Task AuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedContext arg)
        {
            // For debugging purposes only!
            var s = $"AuthenticationFailed: {arg.Exception.Message}";
            arg.Response.ContentLength = s.Length;
            arg.Response.Body.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s), 0, s.Length);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the nuget package `Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory` instead:

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAd:Audience"]
    },
    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAd:AADInstance"]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ..Wot namespace should i use in order to use UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication. i m getting error  iapplicationbuilder don't contain definition for  UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication

Comment: You need to install the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory` nuget package. The extension method on `IAppBuilder` is inside the class `WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationExtensions`.

Comment: How's it going @ashishjayara ?

Comment: Hi ..Apologies for late reply i did the same and it worked but now its giving another  error on  TokenValidationParameters    Says it claims to be in System.Identitymodel.Tokens.jwt  but could not be found @peco

Comment: Im not sure I understand but you can turn on logging for ADAL. This answer helped me once https://stackoverflow.com/a/33272736/1157185

Comment: i am pissed of totally but got nothing  .all i am getting is Core API 1.1 code which i already have, i am stuck with core API 2.0 @peco